# Barendregt's Variable Convention: what does it mean?

Tags: lambda-calculus, variable-binding

Barendregt's Variable Convention: If $M_1,...,M_n$ occur in a certain mathematical context (e.g. definition, proof), then in these terms all bound variables are chosen to be different from the free variables.

This convention appears a lot in papers and I always wonder what does it mean. I want to know exactly what it is saying. I have two ideas about it

when you working on the theory

1. always keep a bound variable's name different from the names of variables at a particular time (Note:two bound variables may have same names)
2. always keep a bound variable name different from name of other bound variables name and all free variable names (every name is distinct)

Variable convention does not mention about if we can have two bound variables  with same names, but I feel variable convention also implies such distinctiveness of bound variables.

So anyone clarify it to me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a device to pretend that one is taking syntax seriously. After you've implemented type theory and/or a programming language several times, you stop believing that  variable capture can be done by humans in textbooks.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @alim The point is: avoiding variable capture is trivially doable in theory, exploiting alpha-conversion, but painful and boring to do explicitly every time in proofs and definitions. Worse, despite it being trivial, it's very easy to get it wrong at first, e.g. by forgetting to alpha-convert, or by alpha-converting to a non completely fresh name. When you try to write an interpreter (or several ones) of a language, this often _has_ to be done, no matter how tedious or error-prone it is. After one tries, and sees how easy it is to get it wrong, one starts to understand the pain.

Comment: @chi. so variable convention also assume all bound variables are distinct at a time?

Comment: @alim In papers, which are meant for humans instead of computers, carefully handling alpha-conversions is boring, error-prone and detrimental to presentation. The Barendregt convention basically says "we know one should handle renaming more precisely, but we won't -- we instead pretend that closed terms are considered up-to alpha, but still dissect them structurally when needed, without really checking that what we do does not depend on the choice of the bound names, since it is so boring".

Comment: @alim Usually, that is not needed: bound variables with non-intersecting scopes can have the same name. But, if a paper needs that for some reason, then yes, the BC can cover that as well.

Comment: @chi I am asking this because of  $(\lambda x.xx)\lambda m \lambda n. m n $ ask renaming to avoid capturing of variables later steps. So I want to know if variables convention means "keep all bound variables distinct by renaming" . I understand the differences of the theory and practice when it comes to renaming. I just want to know what variable convention means exactly.

Comment: @alim Keeping all bound variable distinct is in the spirit of the convention, yes, and is sufficient to avoid capture problems. It is not necessary, in that sometimes you can perform fewer renamings than those. But, as a thumb rule, keeping all the binders distinct is an excellent strategy when one is still learning.

Comment: The real pain actually starts not when you implement bound variables (no renaming is necessary there) but when you want to prove meta-theorems about syntax, or God forbid, that your programs work correctly.

Comment: @chi but the convention did not explicitly say about keep all bound variables distinct, only say keeping bound variables different from free variables. I am trying to understand whether or not variable convention says all bound variables should be taken distinct.

Comment: @alim I would say that is nor required by the convention, but it is completely in its spirit. I would say, not required, but allowed. Just consider terms up to alpha when it is convenient to do so.

Comment: @chi  thank you for your useful discussions, I think I learned what I was trying to know :)